# Blocking IO call in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I click on a button, it stays "clicked" until the executed method finishes.

```html
<button :disabled="!query.length" @click="callExternal">Check</button>
```

```js
methods: {
    callExternal() {
        var request = require("request-promise");
        var options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: `https://external.url/${this.query}`,
            json: true,
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer xyv'
            }
        };

        request(options).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.country = response;
            this.error = false;
        }).catch(err => {
            this.country = '';
            this.error = true;
        })
    }
}
```

I tried the same with axios, but have problems with CORS. With request and request-promise it works. (No clue why!)

What should I do, that the button immediately switch back and don't "freeze"?
Do I have to use async / await?

Comment: The network request is non-blocking, so I can't see that being the cause.  Maybe the `require` is doing a lot of computations? It's unusual to have it inside the method anyway, can you move it out of the method and into file/module scope (at the top of your file)?

Comment: @DecadeMoon Thanks for the hint! Yes, looks like the `require` is the problem. I will try to move it.